# Xamarin : ImportAfter is not a valid short file name

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have an error when I try to install the last stable version of Xamarin or If I want to uninstall Xamarin.

My configuration in Visual Studio:

[image: My configuration in Visual Studio]

I install the last stable version of Xamarin and I have the following error :

[image: error]

I have the same error if I try to uninstall Xamarin:

What can I do?

I can not use Xamarin now.

Comment: It looks like there is already a bug report filed about this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44854

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did the steps described in the bugzilla link posted from jgoldberger: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44854   > see the answer from "Adam Hill, 2016-09-29 02:10:51 UTC".

In Addition on my system: Xamarin searches/needs a Folder "E:\ImportAfter" (from a the past installation perhabs?!). In the meantime the drive letter changed on my system from E: to H: . After i reassigned the driveletter "E:", the repair over "programms & features" worked.
Hope this helps someone else - sorry for my english! ;o)

In Addition, i just saw this bug Report now, which i think is related to this problem:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38751

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an external hard-drive that is usually connected to my docking station. I found the ImportAfter folder on it. After connecting it to my laptop, the setup installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, after a lot of googling and reading a lot of forums, I cant believe it just gone by only a restart windows!!!